# Mustache.js - dont want to update particular div table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handlebars.js, mustache

I am using Mustache.js for rendering tables in a html page. I have a rendering template for the table.
I am getting the view data from json array and render the tables . if the arrary has 5 objects then 5 tables will get created in the html page.
Now I have requirement not to render specific table. For example , i want to render only table1 and table3 . 
If I remove other table values in json it is getting removed from the UI. But I want to retain all the tables but update only the two.
How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not perfect, but you could render everything then hide the tables you do not wish to see? Could you post some code?

Comment: @DanielShillcock , I dont want to hide the table . code is not available.

Comment: In order to help, code is required!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your solution here is going to be ideal since mustache.js is designed as a [logic-less](https://mustache.github.io/#content) templating system.  However, I fudge together some logic like this from time to time with mustache so let's do that.

What you'll likely want to try here is to add another property to each object in your array (or clone it and add the property just for the templating) before rendering the template.  So, let's assume you have five objects in an array and only want to create tables for the even-indexed ones:

```
var myArray = [
  {myProp: 1},
  {myProp: 2},
  {myProp: 3},
  {myProp: 4},
  {myProp: 5}
];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  myArray[i].showTable = i % 2 === 0;
}
```

Now the myArray variable should like something like this:

```
var myArray = [
  {myProp: 1, showTable: false},
  {myProp: 2, showTable: true},
  {myProp: 3, showTable: false},
  {myProp: 4, showTable: true},
  {myProp: 5, showTable: false}
];
```

You can now take advantage of the showTable property through the "#" operator in mustache.  You can use "#" first to iterate through the array and then inside the "loop" to check the truth value of the showTable property.  First, here's the call to Mustache.render to create the HTML from the template, passing our myArray variable as TableArray:

```
Mustache.render($('#MyTemplate').html(), { TableArray: myArray });
```

Then, the template itself:

```
<script id="MyTemplate" type="text/template>
  {{#TableArray}} <!--Iterates through array-->
    {{#showTable}} <!--Only creates HTML inside if showTable property evaluates to true-->
      <table>...</table>
    {{/showTable}}
  {{/TableArray}}
</script>
```